# Why isn't my git pre-commit hook running?

Tags: git, husky

Up until recently -- I only noticed this a couple days ago -- my git pre-commit hook was working. I'm writing a react app and using Husky, TSLint, and Prettier to clean and lint my code before committing. Now, when I change and commit files, the pre-commit hook doesn't run.

My project structure looks like this:

```
- project
  - .git/
  - react/   <- the frontend
    - node_modules/
    - src/
    - package.json
    - (other files)
  - nodejs/  <- the server
    - node_modules/
    - src/
    - package.json
    - (other files)
  - package.json
  - (other files)
```

If I manually execute the hook, it seems to run fine:

```
[/project/react] # git status
On branch fixHusky
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   MyFile.ts

[/project/react] # ../.git/hooks/pre-commit
husky > pre-commit (node v12.6.0)
  ↓ Stashing changes... [skipped]
    → No partially staged files found...
  ✔ Running linters...

[/project/react] #
```

But when I actually try to commit, husky doesn't run:

```
[/project/react] #  git commit -m "testing husky"
[fixHusky cf17a6b] testing husky
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

[/project/react] #
```

Any idea why it isn't running?

Comment: Why `../.git/hooks/pre-commit` and not `./.git/hooks/pre-commit`? Maybe do you have two directories `.git` (`../.git` and `./.git`)?

Comment: Did you put the hook in your package json?

Comment: I used `../` instead of `./` because our project has two directories, one for a server and one for react. The git repo is in the root but the linting should only happen in the react folder. I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Updating Husky by running `yarn add --dev husky` fixed the problem. I have no idea why it stopped working, but husky was very out of date anyways.

Answer (score 6):

Check if [git config core.hooksPath](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) has been set to a different path than its default: `$GIT_DIR/hooks`

Check also that `GIT_DIR` (environment variable) is *not* currently set.

In both cases, Git would look for that hook *not* where you would expect (and currently have your pre-commit hook)

Comment: It looks like both are empty. What should GIT_DIR be set to? Without it, I tried setting the hooksPath manually: `git config core.hooksPath "hooks/*"` but no dice.